# Sporadic black screen when performing segue in iOS 9.2.1 / XCode 7.2

Tags: ios, iphone, segue

**Upvoters: can you let me know if you've seen this problem as well?**

The issue I'm seeing occurs roughly every 1 in 15 times when I try to modally launch a view controller from a button on a certain scene.

This is done with iOS 9.2.1 and XCode 7.2, though it is not clear which versions it happens on. It's not easy to change the iOS version down.

The symptoms are as follows:

1. The destination view controller is not visible on the phone. Instead, the top bar (the one with the carrier) goes black, and sometimes it flickers so the whole screen is completely black. The launching view controller is visible, but not responsive.
2. When this happens, I go to the XCode screen and do view debugging. Remarkably, this shows the destination screen, almost as it's supposed to look. The only difference is that one of the views has not done its drawRect, and one of the other views looks all speckled. But of course it does not at all correspond to what the phone is showing.
3. The cancel button on the destination screen seems to still work, because when I press where it's supposed to be, the app continues to function. If I try to relaunch the screen with the button, it again doesn't work though. So once this has happened, the screen has stopped working for that session and the app needs to be killed and restarted.

There are not many hints, but this information may help:

- There's 3 scrollviews containing views on the destination screen. All three child views have their own drawRect. It turns out one of the drawRects is not called when the error occurs, resulting in the grey background being shown. The speckled view does run, but I have no clue why it looks like that in view debugging.
- No warnings in XCode. Nothing about NSLayout constraints or presentations overlapping.
- Two fields are set on the destination view controller on the prepareForSegue function.
- The segue is launched from the times button by way of the storyboard. There's no missing or extra outlet, and it is named correctly for the prepare function to catch it.

The issue is sporadic, but will reliably occur if you launch/cancel many times in a row.

Here are the screen grabs. I won't show you the black screen. It's just black with the carrier and the time.

[image: The launching screen]

[image: What XCode view debugger shows during black screen]

Comment: Is that second screen shot of a collectionView?

Comment: The second screen has a collectionView at the bottom with 3 dates, but most of it is 3 scrollViews containing custom drawings. The grey area, the dates on the left, and the times on the top.

Comment: Please check Z-order of the controls. I have observed that there is a bug in XCODE which brings some control top. I usually change order for one label and bring back to original again. Sometime that seems to fix it. May fix your problem, but without looking at code it is difficult to answer for me.

Comment: How would the z-order affect the drawing of the entire screen?

Comment: May not be in your case, but worth trying in 1 minute, I had watermark image in background sometimes that comes in top. Some bug in Xcode. If I change the controls z-order in XIB or Storyboard fixes my issue. Just try it. May not be issue on your side.

Comment: I've actually tried to reorder, but to no avail.

Comment: Also please take a look at Apple Documentation, specially drawRect discussion in this link:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawRect:

Comment: I've looked at the docs. What specifically would you think could cause a problem?

Comment: Did you watched memory being used? it is difficult to say what's wrong without looking at code. If possible create a sample app and share code here.

Comment: That's a good idea actually, the memory thing. The code itself is a bit big for me to start peeling away at.

Comment: a) are you using a custom segue? b) can you show how your launching your segue c) modally is it a modal segue?

Comment: Do you add the 3 scrollviews by code and do they have their own different viewControllers? If it's the case, even if they all share 1 different viewController, you need to case addChildViewController and didMoveToParentViewController. If you didn't do that, you can end up in basic calls not being made (like drawRect)

Comment: @DavidYangLiu it's a standard storyboard segue, with no preparation. It's modal.

Comment: @Mikael the 3 scrollviews are supposed to be on the same screen together. Are you saying that they should somehow each have their own viewcontroller, where all 3 are somehow then mashed together in a parent?

Comment: in last screen you have **20:00 pm** :D :P

Comment: @FahimParkar good spot

Comment: @Carlos No you can choose to have the 3 scrollviews inside the same main viewController. But if you actually have those 3 scrollviews in a different viewController that you import in another main viewController then you can end up having issues with the responders'chain if you don't do what I wrote above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. Checking the memory usage turned out to be quite useful.

The grey area was supposed to be filled by a large background with lines drawn. It turns out the naive implementation of drawBackground causes the memory size to balloon to over 200MB. I replaced it with a CSTiledLayer, and now it takes a few MB instead.